# HASH function with 256-bit in Snowflake

Tags: hash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a masking policy in Snowflake (Enterprise version) to mask non varchar characters like Numeric/Integer/Float etc. I want to use hash function with returns 256-bit value.

I tried using HASH(<field_name>) which works fine but returns a 64-bit value. Is there any other hash function which works on number data type and returns 256-bit value. I am also fine if that needs to do type conversion.

Tried with below option but no luck.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE masking policy Stage.ID_Policy as (ID string) returns string ->
CASE
    WHEN current_role() IN ('ACCOUNTADMIN') THEN ID
    --ELSE HASH(ID::NUMERIC(38,0))
    --ELSE HASH_AGG(ID::NUMERIC(38,0))
    --ELSE SHA2_HEX(ID)
    --ELSE CAST(sha2(TO_VARCHAR(ID),256) as NUMERIC)  
    ELSE MD5(ID)
END;
```

Comment: SHA2 and SHA2_HEX both work on numeric types. Did you try using one on those columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 returns 32-characters hex-encoded string. 256 bits makes 32 bytes, so it should be Ok for you if your aim is to get a 256-bit value.

If you need a function that uses a 256-bit digest to hash the data, then you can use SHA2. It will return 64 characters because 4-bits is enough to represent a hexadecimal char.

SHA2 ve MD5 accepts string or binary data, so you don't need to change your string to number as it will be converted to string again.

To return number:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE masking policy Stage.ID_Policy as (ID NUMERIC) returns NUMERIC -> 
  CASE WHEN current_role() IN ('ACCOUNTADMIN') THEN ID 
  ELSE TO_NUMBER(MD5(ID), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')  END;
```

Comment: Just to correct my query - Input is Int/Numeric value and output should be a value with 256-bit value, either it should use HASH or SHA2. Here is my updated query..

Comment: As I said, the input does not matter as it will be converted to a string. 8bit = 1 byte, 256bits/8=32 bytes. So MD5 should work for you?

Comment: I have to apply the masking policy on a table having Numeric column type, which SHA2 doesn't works

Comment: This is my correct query - CREATE OR REPLACE masking policy Stage.ID_Policy as (ID NUMERIC) returns NUMERIC ->
CASE
    WHEN current_role() IN ('ACCOUNTADMIN') THEN ID
    --ELSE HASH(ID::NUMERIC(38,0))
    --ELSE HASH_AGG(ID::NUMERIC(38,0))
    --ELSE SHA2_HEX(ID)
    --ELSE CAST(sha2(TO_VARCHAR(ID),256) as NUMERIC)  
    ELSE MD5(ID)
END;

Comment: how about using TO_NUMBER to convert hex to decimal? select md5(222222222) hashed, TO_NUMBER(hashed, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

Comment: Tried with this query - CREATE OR REPLACE masking policy Stage.ID_Policy as (ID NUMERIC) returns NUMERIC ->
CASE
    WHEN current_role() IN ('ACCOUNTADMIN') THEN ID
    ELSE TO_NUMBER(MD5(ID),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
END;

Comment: The result is - "-78703492656118554854272571946195123045" (ignore double quotes)..............Is it correct?... I am new to Snowflake....

Comment: yes, it seems so. Because MD5 produces a 32byte hexadecimal value which would be very big when it's converted to decimal.

Comment: So, for Numeric we can use MD5 (32-bytes) value is "-78703492656118554854272571946195123045" and for String we can use SHA2 (256-bit) value is "4cc2e826a998d1feecfe82821b60015fdfe971ac367512b67a82850cc1ce2103", which suffice my requirement that both the types are returning 256-bit value?

Comment: Why don't you use MD5 for both? For sting, you don't need to any hex-to-decimal conversion.

Comment: Yes, using MD5 worked charmingly for both the type. Will check if he accepts the result....... A Very BIG Thank you for you prompt support...Really Appreciate :)

Comment: Can we use a proper argument in TO_NUMBER(MD5(ID),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') instead of 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ?

Comment: Each X indicates a digit. I do not know a better way to write it but you may write your own function. And if my response solved the issue, please mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but the way I am reading your code is that you're inputing strings, converting them to numeric and then applying totally different hash functions on the input before outputting as string.

Each hash function has a particular use case and variance in terms of output, and code.

hash_agg requires aggregation, i.e. a group by

Anyway back to your query, if you look up the Wiki for SHA2 the output length would be consistant but I think the 256 bits is referring to the number of bits used, not characters / word size.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

Added tip, try to stick to explicit conversions in data types, because the output cast to numeric in some cases it forces Snowflake to detect the different and apply a cast implicitly -- -that will be slower

Comment: Apologize for the incorrect query. Here is the correct query.                                  
CREATE OR REPLACE masking policy Stage.ID_Policy as (ID NUMERIC) returns NUMERIC ->
CASE
    WHEN current_role() IN ('ACCOUNTADMIN') THEN ID
    --ELSE HASH(ID::NUMERIC(38,0))
    --ELSE HASH_AGG(ID::NUMERIC(38,0))
    --ELSE SHA2_HEX(ID)
    --ELSE CAST(sha2(TO_VARCHAR(ID),256) as NUMERIC)  
    ELSE MD5(ID)
END;